# Knockoutjs likertscale maximum number of points

Tags: knockout.js

What im trying to achieve is the following. Within a list of twenty points a user can select 3 times a 5, 4 times a 4, 5 times a 3 etc.

How can I achieve this with knockout?

I currently have a list with a name, and a observablevar named rating.
Whoe can help me with this?

Example snippet

```
<!-- ko foreach: {data: rateableList } -->
      <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
            <td align="center"><input type="radio" value="nvt" data-bind="checked: rating"></td>
            <td align="center"><input type="radio" value="1" data-bind="checked: rating"></td>
            <td align="center"><input type="radio" value="2" data-bind="checked: rating"></td>
            <td align="center"><input type="radio" value="3" data-bind="checked: rating"></td>
            <td align="center"><input type="radio" value="4" data-bind="checked: rating"></td>
            <td align="center"><input type="radio" value="5" data-bind="checked: rating"></td>
      </tr>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it in a different way like the following.

In the table reference for the radio buttons I added a check if the rating is 5 or the count of rates listed marked as 5.

```
<td align="center"><input type="radio" value="5" data-bind="checked: rating, enable : $root.chosenValueCount()['5'] < 3 || rating() == '5'" /></td>
```

And the JS

```
self.chosenValueCount = ko.computed(function() {
    var result = { 1 : 0, 2 : 0, 3 : 0, 4 : 0, 5 : 0 };
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.rateableList, function(item) {
        if (!result[item.rating()]) result[item.rating()] = 1;
        else result[item.rating()]++;
    });        
    return result;
});
```

You can see a working example at:
http://jsfiddle.net/x7q1gxxf/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a writable computed observable for validation, only writing to the backing field if the validation passes. In your case you would check all the ratings to see if the counts are ok. I've made a simplified example fiddle which only checks if the user does not select "nvt" after choosing some other value.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pe8hg0v6/2/

Javascript:

```
var viewModel;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    var list = [];
    viewModel = {};
    viewModel.isValid = function(value){
        //TODO; your actual validation logic
        return value !== "nvt";
    };

    for(var i=0; i < 5; i++){
        var createObj = function(){
            var obj = {};
            obj.name = "test";
            obj.rating = ko.observable("nvt");
            obj.validatedRating = ko.computed({
                    read: function(){return obj.rating()},
                    write: function(value){if(viewModel.isValid(value)) obj.rating(value);}                
                });
            return obj;
        };
        list.push(createObj());
    }

    viewModel.rateableList = list;
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```